# Slick 3.1.x method returns empty list

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

This method uses Slick 3.1.x and it returns correctly an object of type `Future[List[Analysis]]` however the list is always empty. Why is that and how to fix this?

```
  def readMany = {
    val db = Database.forConfig("db1")
    var list = new ListBuffer[Analysis]()
    try {
        val query = TableQuery[AnalysisDB]
        val action = query.sortBy(_.name).result
        val future = db.run(action).map(_.foreach {
          case (analysis) => list += Analysis ( analysis.sk, analysis.name )
        })
        Future { list.toList }
    } finally db.close
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list is being returned before it is populated. Your `val future` (database call) is being ignored/discarded, and a `Future(list)` (still empty) returned. Try this;

```
def readMany = {
  val db = Database.forConfig("db1")
  try {
    val query = TableQuery[AnalysisDB]
    val action = query.sortBy(_.name).result
    db.run(action).map(_.map {
      a => Analysis(a.sk, a.name)
    })
  } finally db.close
}
```

This also avoids the smelly mutable ListBuffer.

Comment: the method retuns a Vector instead of a List. Note that the action has a `sortyBy`, any chances that the vector could be accessed unordered?

Comment: If you need a List, append `.toList` to the internal `map`: `db.run(action).map(_.map{...}.toList)` 
The ordering will definitely not be lost.